# Vue V-Bind:src always includes local server "localhost:8080" at the beginning. How to set to src to different server?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a web app using vue. I am trying to load images of a strapi cms that I am running and include them via an v-for loop in my component.

When setting the :src for an image, vue always includes the local server that my vue app is running on at the beginning. How do I get around that, so that I can reach the CMS on another port?

I tried different methods of binding the source, including "v-bind:src", ":src", ":src="require()""

```
<div class="images">
  <template v-for="(Image, index) in Images">
    <p v-bind:key="index">{{Image.Image_URL}}</p>
    <img v-bind:key="index" :src="Image.Image_URL" :v-bind:alt="Image.Titel">
  </template>
</div>
```

​​
Output of one of the json objects.

> Date: "24.04.2019",​
>    Place: "Beijing, China",
>   ​​
>   Id: 2,
>   ​​
>   Image_URL: "http:/localhost:1337/uploads/ca472ad50d814fbb963e8b5a5b12742d.jpg",
>   ​
>   Title: "Lights"

I get the image url in a json object. The final url, which is represented here as "Image.Image_URL" is something like: "localhost:1337/uploads/ca472ad50d814fbb963e8b5a5b12742d.jpg". Until now the image src is always get "http://localhost:8080/localhost:1337/uploads/ca472ad50d814fbb963e8b5a5b12742d.jpg" in Vue.

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you provide code of your `Images` object?

Comment: Sure, I have added the first entry of the Images object as a blockquote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one more slash in `http:/localhost:1337/uploads/ca472ad50d814fbb963e8b5a5b12742d.jpg`, should be `http://`

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Sorry, somehow I thought that doesn't matter.